# Using deegree with Oracle DBMS without installing Oracle Spatial?

Tags: oracle-dbms, deegree

I'd like to use *deegree* for its WFS capacities connected to an Oracle 12 database where some geo information are available: stations location (latitude, longitude, altitude) + realtime information (parameters changing each 15 min).

In addition to licence costs for Oracle spatial, it seems to me useless to install it, since all necessary information can be extracted through SQL queries.

How can I use *deegree* with Oracle DB?

Comment: You need spatial features (support for SDO_GEOMETRY data type and spatial indexes) but you get them with the free Locator option. You do not need to acquire the expensive Spatial license. – user30184 35

Comment: Please  [Edit] your Question to contain a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, all Oracle databases in all versions and variants include the **Oracle Locator** feature at no extra licensing costs.

It is the subset of Oracle Spatial that provides full and unlimited support for **2D vector geometries** (points, lines, polygons) for querying and processing (topology and distance-based selections, measurements, overlays, buffers etc).

It is most likely installed in the database you are using - unless the DBA who created that database explicitly went through a custom creation and explicitly unchecked the box that includes it.

You can verify that it is installed by going to SQL*Plus and doing:

```
DESCRIBE SDO_GEOMETRY
```

If this succeeds then you have locator installed.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not installed. It was indeed a limited installation

Comment: So did you get your DBA to install Locator in your database ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Each try to adapt the database ends with many errors like


    ORA-04031: cannot assign 4096 bytes of shared memory

We are using this page [oracle-geospatial-features-spatial-vs-locator](http://houseofbrick.com/oracle-geospatial-features-spatial-vs-locator/)

Comment: Well that indicates that the database is misconfigured in terms of memory parameters. Typically memory is best left to be managed automatically by the database. And adding missing features is best done using the Database Configuration Assistant. If you are still not successful, you can always just log a call with Oracle support.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Spatial is now free. You don’t need to instal it; it is installed by default.